# Using for loop to obtain certain number of inputs?

Tags: java, joptionpane

*emphasized text*I am trying to write a program that collects a user's number of tests and test scores, averages them, and then returns the number of tests, each test score, the average, and the letter grade corresponding to that average.

```
int tests = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Input the number of tests you want to average.", "ClassGrader",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
    while (tests <= 0) {
        tests = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "That is an invalid input.\nTry again.", "ClassGrader",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE));
    }
    for (int runs = 0; runs <= tests; runs++) {

    }
```

*I'd like to know how to offer the user the same amount of input options as the user has test scores.*

I figured the best way to accomplish this would be to use a for statement, although I didn't know what would be a good use of the block statement.

*How can I offer the user the correct number of input options **and then be able to call on each test score** when the final dialog box shows all the information inputted?*

Comment: You need to use array.

Comment: Yes, make an array with the number of tests and fill it in during the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate average you need to `sum` your input and count the input number. Look at sample code,

```
int tests = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Input the number of tests you want to average.", "ClassGrader",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));

int sum=0;
int count=0;
while (tests-- >0) {
   int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Input the number ", "ClassGrader",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    if(num<=0){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "That is an invalid input.\nTry again.", "ClassGrader",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE));
      tests++; // To skip the count of invalid number.
    }
    else{
     sum += num;
     count++;
    }
  }

  double average=(double)sum/count;
```